# Add SVG logo on top of SVG background

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, react-pdf

I am wanting to add an SVG logo that I have (I have the SVG code also) on top of a rectangle with a radial background colour that also contains some title text, however I'm unsure of how to do this.

For context, I am using React-PDF, so the syntax is slightly different.

Currently I have

```
<Svg width="555" height="80" viewBox="0 0 555 80">
    <Defs>
        <RadialGradient id="header-rectangle" cx="0" cy="0" fr="1">
            <Stop stopColor="#A01858"/>
            <Stop offset="1" stopColor="#87005F"/>
        </RadialGradient>
    </Defs>
    <Rect width="555" height="80" rx="8" fill="url(#header-rectangle)"/>
    <Text style={styles.svg} x={`${555-20}px`} y="50%" textAnchor="end" dominantBaseline="middle">Some title here</Text>
</Svg>
```

I then also have my SVG logo (shortened here for conciseness):

```
<Svg width="80" height="52" viewBox="0 0 80 52" fill="none">
    <Path d="M0 47.6941V37.8042C0... fill="green"/>
    ...
</Svg
```

I am wondering how I can add the logo to the main piece...

I have attempted to place the full `<Svg>/*logo*/</Svg>` to the main section, but this produced an error:

[image]

I have also tried moving all of the `<Path>` pieces into the main block, without the `<Svg>` wrapper, which *did* work to some extent, but then I found that I didn't know how to move them down and right...

This is the example:

```
<Svg width="555" height="80" viewBox="0 0 555 80">
    <Defs>
        <RadialGradient id="header-rectangle" cx="0" cy="0" fr="1">
            <Stop stopColor="#A01858"/>
            <Stop offset="1" stopColor="#87005F"/>
        </RadialGradient>
    </Defs>
    <Rect width="555" height="80" rx="8" fill="url(#header-rectangle)"/>
    <Text style={styles.svg} x={`${555-20}px`} y="50%" textAnchor="end" dominantBaseline="middle">Some title here</Text>


    <Path d="M0 47.6941V37.8042C0... fill="green"/>
    /* rest of the logo svg paths here */
</Svg>
```

Comment: `I have also tried moving all of the <Path> pieces into the main block` Are you able to update your question with this attempt?

Comment: @ksav I've added it below that paragraph now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your logo in a group and apply a [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Basic_Transformations) to it

```html
<svg width="555" height="80" viewBox="0 0 555 80">
    <defs>
        <radialGradient id="header-rectangle" cx="0" cy="0" fr="1">
            <stop stop-color="#A01858"/>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#87005F"/>
        </radialGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect width="555" height="80" rx="8" fill="url(#header-rectangle)"/>
    <text x="500" y="50%" text-anchor="end" dominant-baseline="middle">Some title here</text>

    <g transform="translate(20,10) scale(0.5 0.5)">
      <path d="M 10,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30 Q 90,60 50,90 Q 10,60 10,30 z" fill="green" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I thought the `<G>` tag (https://react-pdf.org/svg#g) should do this however when I attempted it, it failed and threw an error... Maybe because I didn't include any `transform` attributes? Thanks for pointing out how it should work :)